# How to Git push from repo A 's branch B to repo C 's branch D?

Tags: git

How to Git push from repo A 's branch B to repo C 's branch D?

I've tried `git push -u C B D`, but git pushed repo A 's branch B to repo C 's new branch B created automatically by Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close :

```
git push C B:D
```

If you add the `-u` option, your local `B` branch will be linked to branch `D` of repo `C`, and not to branch `B` of repo `A` anymore.
This may or may not be what you want ; you can change this anytime by running `git branch -u A/B` or `git branch -u C/D`.